# Unable to validate form with single field, with ajax post

Tags: ajax, django

I've been unable to find a solution to my problem from searching. So I'd like to ask what might be wrong with my code. I'm trying to validate a form from `forms.ModelForm` but in my views function it won't pass the form.is_valid(). printing form.errors gives me:

```
<li>title<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul>
```

Model:

```
class Paper(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Hello World!')
```

forms.FormModel

```
class eventCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        Model = Paper
        fields = ['title']

        widgets = {            
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' :'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Place title'}),          
        }
```

Views

```
def create_paper(request):

    context = {}             

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = paperCreateForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)   

        if form.is_valid():             

            form_data = form.cleaned_data                
            t1 = form_data['title']      
            print(t1)

        else:

            context['create_paper_form'] = form

    form_template = "user/paper-event-template.html"

    return HttpResponse(render_to_string(form_template, {'context' : context}))
```

The form dosen't get validated, and in the else clause it'll pass the error when trying to retrieve it from the `cleaned_data`

I did try and print the form, and it shows:

```
<tr><th><label for="id_title">Title:</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul><input class="form-control" id="id_title" maxlength="100" name="title" placeholder="Place Title" type="text" required /></td></tr>
```

But it dosen't contain any value, which I guess it should: I use a jax method for sending the forms data:

ajax

```
$('#create_paper_form_id').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{% url 'Eapp:create_paper' %}",
            data: { 
                csrfmiddlewaretoken : '{{ csrf_token }}',
                form_data : $('#create_paper_form_id').serializeArray(),

                },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $('.create-paper').html(data);
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('err');
            }
        });
  });
```

html

```
<div class="create-paper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <form class="form" id="create_paper_form_id" novalidate="novalidate" action="{% url 'Eapp:create_event' %}" method="POST">          
            {% for field in create_paper_form %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    {{ field.label_tag }}   
                </div>  
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    {{ field }} 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    {{ field.help_text }}   
                </div>              
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    {{ field.errors }}  
                </div>  
            </div>
            {% endfor %}    
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-6  col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do in your else clause.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Trying to get info on what's wrong.

Comment: Then you should print `form.errors`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's expected behaviour, the `cleaned_data` is only available on a valid form when there's actually cleaned data available.

The `form.data` is still available though, you can use that.

To quote the [manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#the-form-class):

> A Form instance has an is_valid() method, which runs validation
>   routines for all its fields. When this method is called, if all fields
>   contain valid data, it will:
>
> - return True
> - place the form’s data in its cleaned_data attribute.

[edit] As @fazil-zaid mentioned, you need to include `model` in your `Meta` class for it to function as a `modelform`.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I think it might have something to do with my ajax method for sending the post data. So I updated the post. Thanks for the help though.